# different segment of a plot with different colors

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors

I have a list that I want to plot. For each element of the list I have the corresponding color. I want to plot the list with the colors. NO scatter plot.

```
value=[12,15,20] 
color_list=['red','red','blue']
plt.plot(value, color=color_list)
```

I expect to have two segments, first one red and the second one blue.
Thank

Comment: Why do you have 3 colors but 2 line segments? Also are these horizontal lines or do they have an x location?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to plot each line segment separately using a `for` loop and indexing the values you want to plot. Note that you have a color corresponding to each point and not to the line segments, so I indexed at `i+1`to give you the red and blue segments.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

value=[12,15,20]
color_list=['red','red','blue']

for i in range(0,(len(value)-1)):
    plt.plot(value[i:i+2], color=color_list[i+1])

plt.show()
```

[image]

Since you did not provide an x value, this approach assumes each line will go from 0 to 1. If this is not the case, then you need to specify what your x values are and index them in the same manner.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

value=[12,15,20]
xs = [0,1,2]
color_list=['red','red','blue']

for i in range(0,(len(value)-1)):
    plt.plot(xs[i:i+2],value[i:i+2], color=color_list[i+1])

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
    x=np.arange(20)
    y=[i**2 for i in x]

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,5))

    ax.plot(x[0:6], y[0:6], color='red')
    ax.plot(x[5:9],y[5:9], color='blue')
    plt.show()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0MIYD.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).